# How I can output time through SimpledateFormat correctly?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have Java Swing application. And in this application time/data is outputed every step. But it outputs data/time without numbers changes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/298UX.png)

```
private static Date now = new Date();
private static SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
while (true) {
    
        currentDistance = queue1.take().distance + queue2.take().distance;
  
        currentQuelityConsumption = queue1.take().quelityConsumption + queue2.take().quelityConsumption;
       
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(now) + " - Rocket has flied " + String.format("%.2f", currentDistance) + " km. already.\nThe fuel left " + String.format("%.2f", currentQuelityConsumption) + " kg. yet.");
    }
```

How can I output time every step correctly?

Comment: You never change the value of `now`.

Answer (score 0):

## New moment, new object

**Instantiate a new date-time object for each moment** you want to capture. The date-time objects are frozen in time. They do *not* update their own value.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
Instant aMomentLater = Instant.now() ;
Instant anotherMomentEvenLater = Instant.now() ;
```

So in your loop, instantiate a new object each time through.

```
while ( … ) {
    …
    System.out.println( Instant.now().toString() ) ;
    …
}
```

Never use `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat`. Use only the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. This has been covered many many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.